# Loading view to view problems - AngularJS + ui.router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, loading

Having issues when loading views from another view (view to view)

Issue: the destination view is not receiving the proper data to determinate what to display.

Note: Using ui.router

**Index:**

```
    <section ng-if="page.header" ng-class="{'transparent-header': page.transparentHeader}" user-header></section>

   <section ng-class="{'transparent-header': page.transparentHeader, 'create-event-back': page.background}" class="sec-full" ui-view></section>

   <section ng-if="page.footer" user-footer></section>
```

**Router:**

```
.state('LoginPage', {
        url: "/login/",
        data: {
            name: "Login",
            header: false,
            footer: false,
            css: false,
            transparentHeader: false
        },
        templateUrl: "app/partials/common/loginPage.html",
        controller: "loginController"
    })
```

When navigating straight to the view. Everything loads fine but, when i navigate from another view, ex: home view >>>> user view , the `<section>` that holds the navigation bar will not get evaluated ( **ng-if** ).

I don't understand why.

**Updated**
I found the problem. What is happening is:
When i navigate to a page that is restricted, it get redirected to the login page. but the $state is getting the data from the restricted page.

this is what i get in the log:

**Loigin page to state:**

```
Object {name: "Login", header: false, footer: false, css: false, transparentHeader: false}
```

**Restricted pageto state:**

```
Object {name: "Your Profile", header: true, footer: false, css: true, transparentHeader: true…}
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('appController', ['$scope','$state','$rootScope', function($scope,$state,$rootScope){

    //Control header and footer views getting data from router
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState){ 
        $scope.page = toState.data;

    })
}]);
```

Now my question is how to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the data correctly, but you probably aren't accessing it properly!
In the documentation the example states that in order to access the data, you have to use syntax like..

```
$state.current.data.transparentHeader
```

In order to do this, make sure you inject the $state object into your controller as well.

See section "Attach Custom Data to State Objects"
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: i found the problem. im getting the data but the data is changing because the redirection. i will update my question. take a look